# Get function in ydn-db not working in safari and all apple devices

Tags: ios, safari, web-sql, ydn-db

Not sure if it is some bug in ydn-db or I'm doing something wrong. So data is successfully saved in DB with ydn-db and db.values work correct I can get all data from DB. But when I want to get just one data input from DB it works correct in chrome but in safari it can't get single data from DB by ID.

But if I write *ROWID* number, that I can see in inspector in safari, instead of ID in function get, I can get it.

Thing is that I do not know that *ROWID* so I can't get data from DB.

So Is that bug in get function of YDN-DB or it is some my mistake?

this works:

db.values('sections').done(function(data) {console.log(data);});

this do not work in safari and apple devices:

db.get('section', sectionID).done(function(data) {console.log(data);});

thnx

Answer (score 2):

As Kyaw Tun said earlier, defining the keyPath is the key to being able to retrieve the values in WebSQL or Safari.

I just wanted to add that you need to specify the keyPath in the DB Schema each time you wish to create a reference to the DB in Safari.

When ydn is accessing IndexedDB (Chrome) it creates the index and assigns the values you specify to it, in websql (Safari) the primary index is using different values, so when you open the DB Store without a schema, Safari can only query based on its internal primary keys.

So in the case where you are reopening a DB after the browser has closed and your initial reference to the DB is gone, you need to reopen it with your schema.

For example assuming the DB had been populated previously like this
record = {id: '586856', message: 'Testing in line key'};
db.put({name: 'section', keyPath: 'id'}, record);

Accessing records by key from an existing DB like this will work in Chrome but not Safari.

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('SectionDB');
db.get('section', '586856').done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Accessing records by key from an existing DB will work in both Chrome and Safari, if you open the DB with a schema reference like this,

```
var schema = {
  stores:[{
    name:'section',
    keyPath:"id"
  }]
};


var db = new ydn.db.Storage('section', schema);
db.get('section', '586856').done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `db.keys` to get list of keys. You can retrieve using those keys.

Note key are type sensitive. For example number 1 and string '1' are different.

Comment: Thnx but how I can connect this Rowid number with ID that I need? So I put in DB article and ID like this: 

db.put('articles', objectData, objectData._id );

so when i make get function works in chrome but in safari we have rowid, I can get all rowids with keys but I do not know how to connect that rowid with my ID.

So if I have 10 articles and I need one that have id="10" how I will get that in safari? I can get all rowids with db.keys but still I do not know which one is with ID="10"

Comment: Note that ydn-db API is based on IndexedDB and does not have all features of WebSQL. `ROWID` is auto generated keys in IndexedDB terms. So if you use `autoIncrement` key, the primary key is equivalent to `ROWID` in conceptually and actual implementation in ydn-db. It is not possible to get `ROWID` in a query result.

Comment: ok thnx on your time, what is best solution than to get one article by  id. If I put in some data like this: db.put('articles', objectData, objectDataID );

Comment: use primary key `db.get(objectDataID)`. It works for all databases.

Comment: I tried but it wont work like that :)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0dh2t3eb1cwxe0/screen.png

also If I try this db.get('section', "586856").done(function(data) {console.log(data);}); I get this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qx9h0k54wuzj2zf/screen2.png

it is safari, in chrome work correct.

Comment: yes, `db.get('section', "586856")`, my previous one is obviously wrong. It should be `db.get('section', 3363937393637)` however.

Comment: BTW, have you ever define primary key by `keyPath` field in your database store schema? Then, `db.get('section', "586856")` will work.

Comment: Thnx Kyaw Tun now it work ;) now I using this for put in DB and then it work:

record = {id: 'abc', message: 'Testing in line key'};
req = db.put({name: 'store2', keyPath: 'id'}, record);

Thnx a lot keyPath is doing good job :)